# Using a public class function to initialize a nodeType<Type> pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I posted a similar question about this, but I'm asking again, because I was wrong in my attempt. So it's a completely different question now.
This is part of a school project about a linked list of Payroll objects. The feedback from my Professor stated that I need to traverse the linked list from  **inside** the InList function. I understand what he's saying, but not how to do it.
In the InList function, I pass a linked list and an int, create the Payroll object and assign the int as the employee number variable. Then using the nodeType current pointer, traverse the list and print the record if found.

```
    void InList(const orderedLinkedList<Payroll>& P, int employee_number)
    {
    int listCount = P.length();
    Payroll object;
    object.setEmployeeNumber(employee_number);
    nodeType<Payroll> *current; //how to initialize this?
    if (P.isEmptyList())
        cout << "Sorry, there is nothing in the list yet." << endl;
    else
    {
        while (current != NULL && listCount > 0)
        {
            if (current->info.getEmployeeNumber() == employee_number)
            {
                current->info.printPayroll();
            }
            listCount--;
            current = current->link;
        } //end while
    } //end else
    }
```

And here are all the functions for the linked list. Please note, that this header file does not have any member variables, and is derived from a virtual base class that has the first and last pointers. Also note, that first and last are protected in the base class.

```
template <class Type>
bool orderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) const
{
    bool found = false;
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;  //start the search at the first node

    while (current != NULL && !found)
        if (current->info >= searchItem)
            found = true;
        else
            current = current->link;

    if (found)
        found = (current->info == searchItem); //test for equality

    return found;
}//end search

template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent = NULL;//pointer just before current
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;  //pointer to create a node

    bool  found;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
    newNode->info = newItem;   //store newItem in the node
    newNode->link = NULL;      //set the link field of the node
                               //to NULL

    if (first == NULL)  //Case 1
    {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        current = first;
        found = false;

        while (current != NULL && !found) //search the list
            if (current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }

        if (current == first)      //Case 2
        {
            newNode->link = first;
            first = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else                       //Case 3
        {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;

            if (current == NULL)
                last = newNode;

            count++;
        }
    }//end else
}//end insert

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
{
    insert(newItem);
}//end insertFirst

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
{
    insert(newItem);
}//end insertLast

template<class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent = NULL; //pointer just before current
    bool found;

    if (first == NULL) //Case 1
        cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
    else
    {
        current = first;
        found = false;

        while (current != NULL && !found)  //search the list
            if (current->info >= deleteItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }

        if (current == NULL)   //Case 4
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the "
            << "list." << endl;
        else
            if (current->info == deleteItem) //the item to be 
                                             //deleted is in the list
            {
                if (first == current)       //Case 2
                {
                    first = first->link;

                    if (first == NULL)
                        last = NULL;

                    delete current;
                }
                else                         //Case 3
                {
                    trailCurrent->link = current->link;

                    if (current == last)
                        last = trailCurrent;

                    delete current;
                }
                count--;
            }
            else                            //Case 4
                cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the "
                << "list." << endl;
    }
}//end deleteNode
```

And here is the virtual base class:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef H_LinkedListType
#define H_LinkedListType
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
//Definition of the node
template <class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};
template <class Type>
class linkedListIterator
{
public:
    linkedListIterator();
    linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr);
    Type operator*();
    linkedListIterator<Type> operator++();
    bool operator==(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const;
    bool operator!=(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const;
private:
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to point to the current 
};
template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type>::linkedListIterator()
{
    current = NULL;
}
template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type>::
linkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr)
{
    current = ptr;
}
template <class Type>
Type linkedListIterator<Type>::operator*()
{
    return current->info;
}
template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListIterator<Type>::operator++()
{
    current = current->link;
    return *this;
}
template <class Type>
bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator==
(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
{
    return (current == right.current);
}
template <class Type>
bool linkedListIterator<Type>::operator!=
(const linkedListIterator<Type>& right) const
{
    return (current != right.current);
}
//*****************  class linkedListType   ****************
template <class Type>
class linkedListType
{
public:
    const linkedListType<Type>& operator=
        (const linkedListType<Type>&);
    void initializeList();
    bool isEmptyList() const;
    void print() const;
    int length() const;
    void destroyList();
    Type front() const;
    Type back() const;
    virtual bool search(const Type& searchItem) const = 0;
    virtual void insertFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    virtual void insertLast(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    virtual void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem) = 0;
    linkedListIterator<Type> begin();
    linkedListIterator<Type> end();
    linkedListType();
    linkedListType(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList);
    ~linkedListType();
protected:
    int count;   //variable to store the number of elements in the list
    nodeType<Type> *first; //pointer to the first node of the list
    nodeType<Type> *last;  //pointer to the last node of the list
private:
    void copyList(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList);
};
template <class Type>
bool linkedListType<Type>::isEmptyList() const
{
    return(first == NULL);
}
template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType() //default constructor
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::destroyList()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;   //pointer to deallocate the memory
                            //occupied by the node
    while (first != NULL)   //while there are nodes in the list
    {
        temp = first;        //set temp to the current node
        first = first->link; //advance first to the next node
        delete temp;   //deallocate the memory occupied by temp
    }
    last = NULL; //initialize last to NULL; first has already
                 //been set to NULL by the while loop
    count = 0;
}
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::initializeList()
{
    destroyList(); //if the list has any nodes, delete them
}
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::print() const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;    //set current so that it points to 
                        //the first node
    while (current != NULL) //while more data to print
    {
        cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->link;
    }
}//end print
template <class Type>
int linkedListType<Type>::length() const
{
    return count;
}  //end length
template <class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::front() const
{
    assert(first != NULL);

    return first->info; //return the info of the first node 
}//end front
template <class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::back() const
{
    assert(last != NULL);

    return last->info; //return the info of the last node   
}//end back
template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::begin()
{
    linkedListIterator<Type> temp(first);

    return temp;
}
template <class Type>
linkedListIterator<Type> linkedListType<Type>::end()
{
    linkedListIterator<Type> temp(NULL);

    return temp;
}
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::copyList
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create a node
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    if (first != NULL) //if the list is nonempty, make it empty
        destroyList();
    if (otherList.first == NULL) //otherList is empty
    {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        current = otherList.first; //current points to the list to be copied
        count = otherList.count;
        //copy the first node
        first = new nodeType<Type>;  //create the node
        first->info = current->info; //copy the info
        first->link = NULL;        //set the link field of the node to NULL
        last = first;              //make last point to the first node
        current = current->link;     //make current point to
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;  //create a node
            newNode->info = current->info; //copy the info
            newNode->link = NULL;       //set the link of newNode to NULL
            last->link = newNode;  //attach newNode after last
            last = newNode;        //make last point tothe actual last node
            current = current->link;   //make current point to the next node
        }//end while
    }//end else
}//end copyList
template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::~linkedListType() //destructor
{
    destroyList();
}//end destructor
template <class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
{
    first = NULL;
    copyList(otherList);
}//end copy constructor
 //overload the assignment operator
template <class Type>
const linkedListType<Type>& linkedListType<Type>::operator=
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList)
{
    if (this != &otherList) //avoid self-copy
    {
        copyList(otherList);
    }//end else

    return *this;
}
#endif
```

He stated that I can access all the public functions from the main program, and use the function that returns the first pointer to the list, to initialize the current pointer. How do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have code for the virtual base class?  I don't see any member functions here that publicly expose `orderedLinkedList::first`, so the function your professor mentioned must be in the base class.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles yes, I'll edit and add it. That was my problem also, I didn't see where first was returned.

Comment: Your list class is lacking a way to get the first ***node*** in the list, something like `Type* head() { return first; }` and `const Type* head() const { return first; }`.

Comment: @kfsone yes, exactly. I was not seeing anyway to return first from orderedLinkedList. Your suggestion was pretty much what a class-mate came up with, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the linked list uses the standard `begin()` function, which gives you an iterator.  Your code will need to use the iterator to go through each node -- you will never handle node pointers directly.

So your `InList` will start by getting the iterator:

```
linkedListIterator<Payroll> iter = P.begin();
```

You access the iterator node's Payroll object with `*iter`

You advance the iterator to the next node with `++iter`

But before doing these things, you have to make sure you aren't at the end of the list.  To check if not at the end, you can use `if(iter != P.end()) {...}`

I'll hold off on putting those together right now -- I wouldn't want to spoil your fun!

**Edit:**

It looks like `*iter` might not be the best way to access the Payroll object.  For accessing Payroll members, you should be able to use the `->` operator.

Something like `iter->info.getEmployeeNumber()`

**Edit**

It doesn't seem like a good idea to use this, but this is the member function you could add to `orderedLinkedList` to get `first` from a const reference.

Declaration (inside `class orderedLinkedList ... {` block, in a public section):

```
const nodeType<Type>* GetHeadNode() const;
```

Definition:

```
template <class Type>
const nodeType<Type>* orderedLinkedList<Type>::GetHeadNode() const {
    return first; 
}
```

You will probably need to make sure any member functions you access in your Payroll class using this pointer are also `const`.  It should still work if you remove `const` from `const nodeType<Type>*`, if you really need to do that.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I'm still weak with pointers. My Professor was stressing a nodeType pointer. A class-mate came up with the idea to just create a function in orderedLinkedList with nodeType as the return method, and just return first. That seems to work, but I can't use const with my list variable. I struggle with const as well.

Comment: The user of a container object is usually kept isolated from its inner workings -- users are usually never expected to deal directly with pointers, especially if an iterator is provided.  Anyway, I'll edit my answer with a way to get `first` from a `const orderedLinkedList<Payroll>&`, if you are allowed to edit the orderedLinkedList code.

Comment: Well I've been told not to alter code that is within functions of assigned header files, but the reason given was that you want to keep the user entry out of the method of the class. Which I get because you want to validate it first, then enter the function. But, yes I would appreciate seeing a way to get first with a const list.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried that and I was presented with "a value of type "const nodeType<Payroll>* " cannot be assigned to an entity of type "nodeType<Payroll>* "

Comment: Yeah, get rid of `const` in the return type, or change `nodeType<Type> *current;` to `const nodeType<Type> *current;`.  I suspect you will run into const-correctness problems in your Payroll class if you access it from a `const` pointer, however.